# Validation form unique Laravel 5.4 doesn't work

Tags: php, html, forms, laravel, validation

I have this simple code:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'email' => 'required|email|unique:subscriptions'
]);
```

However I can keep putting in the same email and it doesn't send me back and error and keeps creating the row in the database.

However if I change the code to ..

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'email' => 'required|email|unique:users'
]);
```

It sends me back an error properly and displays in the div I have setup for it.

I have tried many different ways to fix this, but I feel like it should be easier than this.  I looked at everything and it doesn't seem to address this issue.  Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to specify the column name**

```
 $this->validate($request, [
    'email' => 'required|email|unique:subscriptions,email'
   ]);  

  $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email'
  ]);
```

**While updating you need to force a unique rule to Ignore Given ID**

```
'email' => 'unique:subscriptions,email,'.$user->id
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-unique